# The pullback of 1-forms on $\textrm{Gl}(n;\mathbb R)$ by an exponential map.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

This is from P53 of *Differential Geometry* by Taubes. 
Fix some $q\in \textrm M (n;\mathbb R)$. Set the 1-form $\omega_q$ on $\textrm{Gl}(n;\mathbb R)$ 
$$\omega_q|_m=\textrm{tr}(qm^{-1}\textrm d m),$$
where $\textrm d m$ denotes the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\textrm dm_{i,j}$.
The exponential map $e_\iota$ is
$$e_\iota: \textrm M (n;\mathbb R) \to \textrm{Gl}(n;\mathbb R),m\mapsto e^m.$$
Then Taubes asserts that the pullback of $\omega_q$ by $e_\iota$ is
$$e_\iota^*\omega_q=\int^1_0 \mathrm{d}s~ \text{tr}(e^{-sa}qe^{sa}\textrm da).$$
That's where I stuck. Why the pullback is like that?

Comment: I don't understand what the $1$-form $\omega_q$ is. Please be more clear about this.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval $\textrm d m$ denotes the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\textrm dm_{i,j}$.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @wilkersmon No, I did not find the answer.

Comment: @user150248 take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194344/how-to-write-down-the-pull-back-of-a-differential-form-by-exponential-map